# JQuery: Getting content from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form that is targeted to an IFRAME when "submit" is pressed.
This iframe then loads a page (after submit is pressed) that reports whether the data input by the user is valid or not. It simply shows on screen "TRUE" or "FALSE".
I want JQuery to check this text on the loaded iframe, and refresh the page if it displays "TRUE".

The question is:
How can JQuery get the content of a Iframe?

ps: The FORM sends files. So load() is not an option.

Comment: why not use jquerys .lod() function instead of an iframe?

Comment: because the form has enctype multiform. It sends files.

Answer (score 0):

use jquerys functions .get() or .load() instead of an iframe.  more unobstrusive =)

do the validation before sending any data to the server or saving them on the server using jquery.validation:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. The form sends files. That's why I'm going thru all this trouble.

Comment: do the validation before and use jquery.validate